# Python- find the unique values from a large json file efficienctly

Tags: python, json, large-files

I've a json file **data_large** of size 150.1MB. The content inside the file is of type `[{"score": 68},{"score": 78}]`. I need to find the list of unique scores from each item.

This is what I'm doing:-

```
import ijson  # since json file is large, hence making use of ijson

f = open ('data_large')
content = ijson.items(f, 'item') # json loads quickly here as compared to when json.load(f) is used.
print set(i['score'] for i in content) #this line is actually taking a long time to get processed.
```

Can I make `print set(i['score'] for i in content)` line more efficient. Currently it's taking **201secs** to execute. Can it be made more efficient?

Comment: See also: [This question on CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38574/how-to-find-the-unique-values-from-the-json-file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the set of unique score values (only) as ints.  You'll need the 150 MB of free memory.  It uses re.finditer() to parse which is about three times faster than the json parser (on my computer).

```
import re
import time
t = time.time()
obj = re.compile('{.*?: (\d*?)}')
with open('datafile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
s = set(m.group(1) for m in obj.finditer(data))
s = set(map(int, s))
print time.time() - t
```

Using re.findall() also seems to be about three times faster than the json parser, it consumes about 260 MB:

```
import re
obj = re.compile('{.*?: (\d*?)}')
with open('datafile.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
s = set(obj.findall(data))
```

Comment: I tried your `re.findall` code and yes it increases the time efficiency by quite a huge amount. It was interesting to note such a huge amount of performance. I understood the code, but my question is why is it faster? Kindly provide your opinion on this.

Comment: `for this specific task where the only thing you are doing is extracting the scores` - maybe it is faster because it does not need to figure out, and create, the type of python object the (sub)strings represent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to improve things by much. The slow part is probably just the fact that at some point you need to parse the whole JSON file. Whether you do it all up front (with `json.load`) or little by little (when consuming the generator from `ijson.items`), the whole file needs to be processed eventually.

The advantage to using `ijson` is that you only need to have a small amount of data in memory at any given time. This probably doesn't matter too much for a file with a hundred or so megabytes of data, but would be a very big deal if your data file grew to be gigabytes or more. Of course, this may also depend on the hardware you're running on. If your code is going to run on an embedded system with limited RAM, limiting your memory use is much more important. On the other hand, if it is going to be running on a high performance server or workstation with lots and lots of ram available, there's may not be any reason to hold back.

So, if you don't expect your data to get too big (relative to your system's RAM capacity), you might try testing to see if using `json.load` to read the whole file at the start, then getting the unique values with a `set` is faster. I don't think there are any other obvious shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

On my system, the straightforward code below handles 10,000,000 scores (139 megabytes) in 18 seconds.  Is that too slow?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-2.7/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function

import json  # since json file is large, hence making use of ijson

with open('data_large', 'r') as file_:
    content = json.load(file_)
    print(set(element['score'] for element in content))
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using a set

```
set([x['score'] for x in scores])
```

For example

```
>>> scores = [{"score" : 78}, {"score": 65} , {"score" : 65}]
>>> set([x['score'] for x in scores])
set([65, 78])
```

Comment: You're suggesting that the questioner use the exact code he's asking how to improve. That doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: I used generator. Using generator is often considered efficient.

Comment: Haven't noticed. sorry.